# Boundary Value Problem of Holomorphic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded open connected set. Let $f: \partial U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Is it always possible to find continuous function $u: \overline{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $u: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $u =f $ on $\partial U$?

We have Poisson formula and Cauchy integral formula, and we sometimes talk about the boundary value problem for Laplace equation. But I'm not sure what happens if we consider holomorphic functions, instead of harmonic functions.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If $u$ is holomorphic inside $U$ and real-valued on the boundary then it is necessarily constant. Or did you mean $f: \partial U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Actually I got a question that why it is more difficult(?) to solve a boundary value problem for harmonic functions rather than holomorphic functions. The question is a little vague, so I'm trying to think about some special cases or find some theorems that might explain it. I think $f: \partial U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the better assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f$ is *real*-valued (as Martin R) pointed out, there is *never* a nonconstant solution $u$. Indeed, the imaginary part of $u$ will be continuous on $\overline{U}$, harmonic in $U$ and zero on the boundary, so it will vanish identically by the maximum principle. So $u$ will be real-valued and holomorphic hence constant.

When $f$ is complex-valued, the answer is still in general no (some nontrivial $f$ will still work, even though “most” won’t). Take $U$ to be the unit disk, and $f$ be the complex conjugation. Assume that there is some satisfactory $u$. Then, for any $0 < r < 1$, $\int_0^1{u(re^{2i\pi\theta})e^{2i\pi\theta}\,d\theta}=0$ because $u$ is holomorphic inside $U$.

Thus (by continuity) $0=\int_0^1{e^{2i\pi\theta}u(e^{2i\pi\theta}\,d\theta}=\int_0^1{d\theta}=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Note that OP required the boundary values to be real-valued (which makes the problem even simpler).